# shared model across controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

right now in each of my controller classes i am instantiating a new Repository class to access my DB. Is there a way i can simply create this once (a single repository instance shared across all controllers) and pass into all controllers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyOwnControllerFactory());
```

In your factory you can set up your repository and pass to ALL controllers.

But of course you better use [IoC containers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx). They have option to create repository once per request / once per app lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Dependancy Injection (or create a base class for all your controllers)

Comment: Creating a base class won't share the instance, which I assume he's trying to do.